# FOR XML Syntax - Does it work in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I'm using the **FOR XML PATH** syntax in SQL Server 2005 to generate XML from a SQL Query.

Is the FOR XML PATH syntax supported in SQL Server 2005 Express editions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes - absolutely!** Just try it - it will work.